# SQL - Join two tables and conditionally select rows based on value from a categorical column

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have two tables with **inner** join. I have to conditionlly select only one row from right table based on the existence of a value in categorical column.

**Condition**: If blue exists, select blue else select green

**Table-A:**

```
| ID | Name  |
| ---| ------|
| 01 | row   |
| 02 | row   |
| 03 | row   |
```

**Table-B:**

```
| ID | CatCol  |
| ---| --------|
| 01 | blue    |
| 01 | green   |
| 01 | red     |
| 02 | green   |
| 02 | red     |
| 03 | blue    |
```

**Expected**:

```
| ID | CatCol  |
| ---| --------|
| 01 | blue    |
| 02 | green   |
| 03 | blue    |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select a.ID, string_agg(CatCol, '' order by if(CatCol = 'blue', 1, 2) limit 1) CatCol
from table_a a left join table_b b
on a.ID = b.ID and CatCol in ('blue', 'green')
group by ID
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I went with a similar approach but with a window function (OVER with PARTITION BY).

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
SELECT b.ID, MIN(b.CatCol) as CatCol 
FROM table_b b
INNER JOIN table_a a ON 
b.id = a.id
GROUP BY b.ID
```